# Can iTunes ignore store credit and use a credit card instead?

Tags: itunes, ios-appstore, accounts

There are times when I've got some store credit from a gift card/certificate on iTunes, but I want to buy something without that.

**I want to buy something with the credit card, regardless of what's prepaid on the account.**

Is this possible?

Comment: This isn't exactly what you want to achieve but it has the same net effect in terms of balances.  Purchase an iTunes gift card for whatever amount you wanted to spend on the credit card.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to [Apple's page](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1574), it uses the following order for song purchases:

- Song credits.
- Gift certificate, prepaid card, or allowance credits.
- Credit cards.

Thus, it would appear that you cannot charge a credit card without using up your credits or gift certificates first.

However, similar to what @Nick said, you could just open up another account, add the credit card to it, and then gift the items you want to your original account.

**Update:** Based on my own tests of self-gifting, these are my findings:

- Gifts will deduct money from the credit card on your account; they will not use up song credits nor gift card credit. This means that you do not need to open another account, just add it as a credit card and gift it to yourself.
- You cannot send a gift to the same email address as your iTunes account. This can easily be circumvented by sending it to one of your other email accounts.
- The easiest method of gifting to yourself is to select the print option. It will show you a code which you then use to redeem the song. It will allow you to redeem the code on the same account.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly for you, iTunes uses credit in the store before using a credit card.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you "gift" something you will use a credit card instead of store credit since you can't buy a gift with store credit.

Comment: can I gift something to myself?

Comment: @Nathan: see [my answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6827/can-itunes-store-ignore-store-credit-and-use-credit-card-instead/9737#9737) above which explains how to self-gift.